# Kit suggestion for programmable, weatherproof, speaker

Tags: localisation, recommendations, speakers

Has anyone got recommendations for a battery powered metronome/speaker that could be used to emit a regular sound over a period of ~1 week and a radius of 100-200m outside, so that it could be used to time-sync 4 or 5 recording units for localisation?

Answer (score 3):

have you considered using a Minirig 3? These are super powerful yet compact (W = 101.6mm H = 73mm), high quality speakers with built in amplifier (40W), big on the festival scene. Battery life is around 100+ hours. You can connect to it via bluetooth or a 3.5mm lead.

https://minirigs.co.uk/speakers/bluetooth-minirig-3

I've used one in the field before and it was great, with some minor weatherproofing. For producing a time-sync signal I think this would work.